# How to measure battery capacity (mAh)?

Tags: battery, hardware, motorola-droid

I've bought an [Android device](https://www.tokopedia.com/snapshot.pl?dtl_id=26058019&order_id=16349061) (Motorola Droid 4) online yesterday, the seller claims that it's 3300 mAh (and that's one of two reason why I bought it), but when I receive the device and check it, there are no printing that show it is 3300 mAh.

I tried to compare with pictures of [Droid 4 battery EB41](https://www.google.com/search?q=droid%204%20battery%20EB41&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch) on the the internet with mine, it looks like that mine is [1735 mAh](http://es.aliexpress.com/item/New-Original-EB41-Li-ion-Mobile-Phone-Battery-For-Motorola-DROID-4-XT894-Free-Tools-1785mAh/2052240277.html), but I could not be sure that it's so.

I've tried to use apps to get the capacity information, but got no luck, I've tried:

- CPU-Z by CPUID
- GSam Battery Monitor by GSam Labs
- Phone Tester (hardware info) by Miguel Torres
- Battery Info by Kadett2
- Battery Monitor Widget by 3c Tools
- Ampere by Braintrapp
- battery indicator free by Adcoms
- CurrentWidget: Battery Monitor by RmDroider

but it always show `0 mAh`, `Unknown` or the `Capacity` label not shown at all.

Here's the photo of my device:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

The question is, is there any way to make sure that my device is really `3300 mAh`? or am I being fooled by the seller?

**EDIT**: thank you for the answers, now I have the proof that the seller lied, or maybe he didn't know that he give me incorrect product. This is the side view, because I don't have correct tool to remove the battery completely:

[image]

Comment: Which Android version? In Lollipop, you can do `adb shell dumpsys batterystats | grep "Capacity:"`.

Comment: I'm using `5.1.1` the output was empty, the complete output (without grep): pastebin.com/17M5ERGe

Comment: Tried battery doctor app?

Comment: @Lucky battery doctor by who? by `Cheetah Mobile Inc` and `Cingdy` seems do not have such information (by the screenshot)

Comment: Yes Battery Doctors by CM will show the current battery capacity..

Comment: @Lucky i have installed it, which part of the UI that shows the battery capacity?

Comment: The first screen after you open the app I guess. Sorry I don't have the app right now installed on my phone. If it's not there just swipe right and check it. It will display the battery's current mAh. Charge your phone 100% to check your battery's full capacity.

Comment: @Lucky no, it shows nothing about `mAh` on this phone..

Comment: How did you pay for your online purchase?  If you paid using a credit card, then which type of credit card did you use?  (e.g. Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover, Diner's Club, etc.)

Comment: no i use debit card

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Motorola Droid 4 XT894](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_droid_4_xt894-4418.php)
has 1785mAh battery with 2% tolerance i.e 1735mAh actual battery capacity.
Your seller seems to have fooled you.
Also it doesn't seem like the seller put up the battery description as 3300mAh by mistake as he has put this in [Title name itself](https://www.tokopedia.com/paipulu/hot-bnob-motorola-droid-4-xt894-16gb-baterai-3300mah-super-murah)

You could have taken out the battery from phone and flipped it to see the battery capacity printed on the other side.

Side 1

[image: Side 1]

---

Side 2
[image: Side 2]

Answer (score 0):

These apps will show the actual full battery capacity in mAh.

[GO Battery Saver&Power Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.gopowermaster&hl=en)

[Battery Monitor Widget Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.bmw.pro&hl=en)

Comment: Those show the "full capacity" reported to Android; from what I can tell they do not tell you the actual real-time capacity of the battery in mAh, nor the cycle count. However, GSAM at least, tracks the charge current and time, so it would be theoretically possible to export that data and calculate the area under the curve.